# Functions declared in llvm-3.5/include/clang-c/Index.h can not be found

Tags: llvm

When building rtags with `cmake -DLIBCLANG_LLVM_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE=/usr/lib/llvm-3.5/bin/llvm-config ..; make`, I found this problem, and I suspect some wrong happens in libclangIndex.a.

```
$ sudo ar -t /usr/lib/llvm-3.5/lib/libclangIndex.a
CommentToXML.o
USRGeneration.o
```

Can anyone give some help ?

Comment: Can you show which functions cannot be found as an example?

Comment: Is there such file as include/Index.h in your llvm version? I just see the one tools/clang/include/clang-c/Index.h

Comment: Yes, I can find file /usr/lib/llvm-3.5/include/clang-c/Index.h, and file /usr/lib/llvm-3.5/lib/libclangIndex.a.  Functions cannot be found, like clang_getCompletionPriority, clang_getCString, clang_getCursorType, clang_disposeString, clang_disposeCodeCompleteResults, etc.

Comment: The command I used to install llvm is `apt-get install llvm-3.5 llvm-3.5-dev`

Comment: Do you have undefined symbols to those functions?

Comment: Yeah, the problem is the definitions of these functions can not be found when linking the program.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by myself. Actually, these functions are not defined in libclangIndex.a, but defined in libclang.a.

```
$ sudo readelf -s  libclang.a | grep clang_getCursorKind
  ...
  1056: 0000000000000000     5 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  284 clang_getCursorKind
  ...
```

but, in order to have libclang.a installed, I run command `sudo apt-get install libclang-common-3.5-dev libclang-3.5-dev`.

Thanks wvoquine for your work.